# How to check if a user re-logged in and accessing the same API in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, microservices

I have a micro service developed in asp.net core 6.0. I need to display error message in a certain scenario if the same user logs out and trying to access the same API for which he got error after re-login.

I am not sure what is best way to find out that the same user re-login and trying to access the API again.

Comment: You can always store the last login time in audit table and check the history. If you want to reduce efforts you can always store it in cookies but you may want to encrypt the data since user/anybody with access to cookies can manipulate it. More about cookies here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies

Answer (score 0):

If you have stored the previous login time of that particular user, you can retrieve that time and check the difference with the current time, if it is less than a certain amount (let's say 1min), then you can throw the error.